# Is a new object created every time a Java Script function is invoked?

Tags: javascript, function

I've just read the following sentence:

> Each time a JavaScript function is invoked, a new object is created containing information about which parameters were passed, how the function was invoked, where the function was called from, and so on.

Is this correct?
If so, given the code below, how can I view this "new object"?

```
function test(){
  console.log("hello");
}
test();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this correct?

*Theoretically*, yes — in fact, according to the spec, there are something like three objects created: A *declarative environment record*, a *lexical environment* object, and the `arguments` pseudo-array. Most people lump the first two together under the name "execution context." This is detailed in [§10.4.3 of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) and the sections it links to. The *lexical enviroment* object has properties for any declared arguments, local variables, the `arguments` pseudo-array, etc. (I've simplified slightly there.) This is how closures (functions that "close over" a context) work: They have a reference to the context in which they were created. (More on my blog: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).)

I say *theoretically* because of course JavaScript engines are free to optimize as long as side-effects of the optimization are not observable. Your `test` function doesn't have any declared arguments, doesn't use the `arguments` pseudo-array, doesn't create any closures, and doesn't refer to itself by its name, and so an engine would be free to not create a context for it at all.

> how can I view this "new object"?

You can't, directly, there's no reference to it available to code. I've frequently wished there were. :-)

Comment: Great answer. +1 for the link to the spec.